# Modify AudioBuffer volume in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, arraybuffer, audiocontext, audiobuffer

How can modify AudioBuffer volume in javascript ?
I just wanna modify AudioBuffer volume without play any sound and without use any gain.
Finally , I wanna to have a new AudioBuffer with modified volume.

Comment: Might be this would help you https://zpl.fi/pitch-shifting-in-web-audio-api/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to multiply all values within an existing `AudioBuffer` by 2. You could do that by looping over all values to apply the computation.

```
for (let channel = 0; channel < audioBuffer.numberOfChannels; channel += 1) {
    const channelData = audioBuffer.getChannelData(channel);

    for (let sample = 0; sample < channelData.length; sample += 1) {
        channelData[sample] *= 2;
    }
}
```

This will edit all values in place. If you want to copy all values to a new `AudioBuffer` instead you can do it as follows.

```
const copiedAudioBuffer = new AudioBuffer({
    length: audioBuffer.length,
    numberOfChannels: audioBuffer.numberOfChannels,
    sampleRate: audioBuffer.sampleRate
});

for (let channel = 0; channel < audioBuffer.numberOfChannels; channel += 1) {
    const channelData = audioBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
    const copiedChannelData = copiedAudioBuffer.getChannelData(channel);

    for (let sample = 0; sample < channelData.length; sample += 1) {
        copiedChannelData[sample] = channelData[sample] * 2;
    }
}
```

The example above creates an `AudioBuffer` with the exact same properties as the existing one. It will leave the existing `AudioBuffer` untouched.